# Java 8 HashMap return String

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a `HashMap` that I want to transform into a SQL *where* clause.  I know how to do this using brute-force way, but I am trying to learn the Java 8 lambda and functional expressions.  I have this code:

```
Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
paramMap.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k + "=" + v));
```

which prints out the comparison, but I am trying to return a String that contains:

```
k1=v1 OR k2=v2 OR k3=v3
```

`forEach` doesn't return anything and it looks like `stream()` and `map()` aren't supported for `HashMap`.

Comment: use `entrySet` then you can stream it

Comment: and just in case : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: when marking as duplicate, can you put a link to the original?  I searched SO and couldn't find the answer which is why I posted.

Comment: I see it now....thanks!